# How do I fix a "Found duplicate file for APK" error in eclipse Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I have a java project A, which depends on junit 4.11

Android project B depends on java project A, and hence gets these hamcrest.jar and junit4.11.jar. This generates the "Found duplicate file for APK" error since there are two LICENSE.txt files.

In gradle we just add:

```
packagingOptions  
{
    pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
}
```

How do I accomplish the same in Eclipse? Is it possible to exclude LICENSE.txt from one of the jars using an eclipse configuration?

Comment: Hello. Have you found the solution yet?